# What is _TypeError and how to handle/test it?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, error-handling, typeerror

When trying to assign a value of a wrong type to a variable in Dart, you get a `_TypeError`.

Example:

```
void main() {
  dynamic x = 1;
  String y = x;
}
```

Output: `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

**What exactly is a _TypeError?** I can't find the documentation. I can't catch it (specifically) or expect it in a unit test.

**Catching**

The following is the only way I could catch it so far, but I don't want to *catch 'em all*. I want to use `on ... catch(e)`., but `on _TypeError catch(e)` doesn't work, because `_TypeError` is undefined.

```
void main() {
  dynamic x = 1;
  try {
    String y = x;
  } catch (e) {
    print('catched: ' + e.runtimeType);
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
catched: _TypeError
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

**Testing**

How to expect it in a unit test? I expected this to work, but it doesn't:

```
test('throws a _TypeError', () {
  dynamic x = 1;
  String x;
  expect(() => x = y, throwsException);
};
```

Output:

```
Expected: throws <Instance of 'Exception'>
  Actual: <Closure: () => dynamic>
   Which: threw _TypeError:<type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_TypeError` is an internal dart class used instead of `TypeError`, so in most cases, you can just use `TypeError` instead:

```
dynamic x = 1;
  try {
    String y = x;
  } on TypeError catch (e) {
    print('caught: ' + e.runtimeType);
    print(e.toString());
  }
```

**Testing**

Sadly, I don't know of any way to test for TypeError, I don't believe they made a matcher for it, but I could be wrong, but I guess you could always test before the cast itself

```
test('throws a _TypeError', () {
  dynamic y = 1;
  String x;
  expect(y, isInstanceOf<String>());
};
```

if the above test fails, so will `x = y;`

Comment: Thanks, catching works perfectly and by knowing about the class `TypeError` I know how to test it, too: `expect(() => x = y, throwsA(isA<TypeError>()));`.